# REST interface to include referenced entities - .NET 4.5, MVC + EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Let's say I have two entities:
1. Order
2. Package

Each package has a foreign key to an order, ie. one order has one or more packages. I created a REST interface to be able to retrieve Orders in JSON format.

```
    public IEnumerable<Order> Get()
    {
        using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
        {
            return db.Order.ToList();
        }
    }
```

I was wondering if there is an elegant way of including the children packages in the above json response, so all packages for each order?

Thanks

Comment: Using database first? Did you set up a navigation property for `Order.Packages` in your edmx file?

Comment: Hi Steven, I am using code-first approach and have no edmx file.